# Next.js staticPageGenerationTimeout not working

Tags: next.js, static-site-generation

I have put this in my `next.config.js` file (Next.js 11.1.3):

```json
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
   sassOptions: {
      includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, "styles")],
   },
   trailingSlash: true,
   staticPageGenerationTimeout: 1000,
};
```

However, the error I get is this:

```
warn  - Restarted collecting page data for /blog/[slug] because it took more than 60 seconds
warn  - See more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/static-page-generation-timeout
```

It's mentioning 60 seconds which is the default value and seems like the custom value I've provided isn't working. What's wrong?

Comment: Is that your full `next.config.js` file?

Comment: @juliomalves Nope, but the two other options are these: ```sassOptions: {
      includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, "styles")],
   },
   trailingSlash: true,```

Comment: did u find a solution?

Comment: @WasifKhalil Not a solution for changing the 60 seconds value yet. However, the issue in my case got solved by changing things in the backend.

Comment: i resolved it, i found that this value is only available in nextjs v12+ so in order to use it you have to upgrade the version

Comment: @WasifKhalil Are you sure? Then post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Shahriar I am having a similar issue which gives ECONNRESET error eventually. What did you change in the backend, maybe that will guide me?

Comment: @GeniusHawlah My backend is a headless WordPress (with GraphQL), and I figured out that disabling some plugins during build time can help. I'm still not sure if this is the real cause of the issue or not, but seems to be it.

Comment: btw, I switched from SSG to ISR + On-demand revalidation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js 11 doesn't have `staticPageGenerationTimeout`. You need to upgrade to 12 or higher.

Of course, if you have to up your timeout you should consider if there is a promise not resolving, an infinite loop, or slow network calls that you can fix before upping the limit. See also [Static page generation timed out after multiple attempts](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/static-page-generation-timeout) on the Next website.

Note: Credit where credit is due. This is answered in the comments but the comment is easy to miss (I missed it at first!) and it's been months, so I'm writing this as an answer in hopes of saving some people time.